# Computer powers off a few seconds after starting boot

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I am trying to repair some friend's of mine PC that won't boot. I have disconnected all devices from the main board and connected it to a new power supply.

Here are the symptoms:

The battery is probably empty, because every time I switch it on I get the messages "CMOS Settings Wrong, CMOS Date/Time Not Set, Press F2 to run Setup, Press F1 to load default values and continue". I will replace the battery as soon as the shops open tomorrow but I do not think this is the cause of the problem. I reported it for the sake of completeness, in case it is relevant.

When I turn on the switch on the power supply, the PC powers on immediately, even though there is a power switch on the front of the desktop. I wonder if the power switch on the case is stuck or malfunctioning.

After I power on, I can enter the BIOS settings and work with it for minutes, everything seems to be OK. I can also open the boot menu (F11 on this main board).

Now, if I try to boot from USB using a [rip-linux](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=rip) image, the system powers off a few seconds after I launched the boot.
So I have connected the floppy drive and tried to boot from there with a [PLOP](https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/index.html) disk image. The result is the same: the system is on even for 15 minutes, but as soon as I boot, it switches off after a few seconds.
I have also tried a FreeBSD installation USB image. It gets pretty far into the boot sequence: it loads the kernel, starts testing devices (e.g. floppy), and then powers off.

So, what can be the cause of this malfunctioning? What happens during boot that can cause the system to power off? The only thing I could think of was that the processor might warm up during boot because it is used more intensively. So I have removed the processor's fan and added some thermal grease. After I did this nothing has changed.

I have also tried putting the main board + power supply in another chassis, just in case the power switch was broken, but the behaviour did not change.

So I am completely out of ideas.

Comment: Maybe it's a hardware fault issue like RAM try taking off RAM's one by one check if the issue persist

Comment: I tried replacing RAM modules but the issue persists. FreeBSD boot starts but it powers off while checking devices. It is too fast to see what was the last thing it checked before powering off.

Comment: I noticed that the FreeBSD boot sequence always gets to the point where is has checked (or has started checking) USB devices. That is the last thing it prints out and then the computer is powered off.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you there is an option in bios can cause such behavior there's an option in power on devices to disable USB on power on ( that's different than disable boot from USB )

Comment: I got a little bit further. Disabled USB in the BIOS and booted from a hard disk on which I had installed FreeBSD. Booted with `boot_pause=1` and stepped through the boot sequence. It recognized most devices (keyboard, Ethernet card, graphics card, etc). The last lines it printed before powering off was: `powernow0: <Cool 'n'Quiet K8> on cpu0`, `random: unblocking devices` ..... power off. It seems to do this consistently, i.e. it powers off every time at this point.

Comment: Disabled `Cool 'n'Quiet` in the BIOS. Last thing I see is `random: unblocking devices`

Comment: I booted with `boot_verbose=1` and filmed the boot so I can watch what happened last. After `random: unblocking device`, `ata0: ...` several lines, `ata1: ...` several lines, then `ata2: SATA connect timeout status=00000000` for half a second and the power off.